# Multiple images through Facebook sharer.php url

Tags: facebook, image, share

Does anyone know how to give the user the option to choose between multiple images when sharing a page on Facebook?

I've used an url like the one below in the past. The images param would be

> p[images][0]=...&p[images][1]=...

etc. However, it seems that this doesn't work anymore. The user sees the arrows to select the next or previous image with but there is only one image to choose from.

**Web page**
http://occasions.dvangorkum.nl/Land-Rover/Range-Rover-Sport-2.7-/TdV6-HSE-Navigatie-PDC-Climate-Xenon-Luchtvering--1606304/1603/1/11/details.aspx?zoek=&so=gallerij

**URL:**
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Foccasions.dvangorkum.nl%2FLand-Rover%2FRange-Rover-Sport-2.7-%2FTdV6-HSE-Navigatie-PDC-Climate-Xenon-Luchtvering--1606304%2F1603%2F1%2F11%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fzoek%3D&p[images][0]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_1.jpg&p[images][1]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_2.jpg&p[images][2]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_3.jpg&p[images][3]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_4.jpg&p[images][4]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_5.jpg&p[images][5]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_6.jpg&p[images][6]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_7.jpg&p[images][7]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_8.jpg&p[images][8]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_9.jpg&p[images][9]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_10.jpg&p[images][10]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_11.jpg&p[images][11]=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.autodealers.nl%2F640%2F1606304_12.jpg&p[title]=++++Land-Rover%C2%A0Range+Rover+Sport+2.7+%C2%A0TdV6+HSE+Navigatie+PDC+Climate+Xenon+Luchtvering+&p[summary]=Occasion+te+koop+aangeboden+Land-Rover+Range+Rover+Sport+2.7++TdV6+HSE+Navigatie+PDC+Climate+Xenon+Luchtvering++uit+2007%2C+187618+km%2C+Diesel%2C+SUV%2C+Automaat%2C+Grijs&so=gallerij

Comment: So what did you do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it seems that this doesn't work anymore.

Yes, the [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/) does not accept these parameters any more after a recent change, but will now get all its info about the shared link from the Open Graph meta information embedded in the shared document.

So if you want multiple images the user can chose from, you have to put multiple `og:image` meta tags into your document. (Be aware that Facebook seems to offer no more than three images to chose from any more, so putting more images in there is pointless.)

For documentation on Open Graph meta information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#creating and http://ogp.me/